# Running a function onclick with a JSON file

Tags: json, function, onclick, reddit

So I'm trying to have a function run when i click on an image. It works with a normal image, but i'm getting the images from a reddit JSON file. I need the images to resize separately and I can't figure out how. It's probably something simple, but i'm still new to coding, so any help would be great.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/.json?jsonp=?", function (data) {
$.each(data.data.children, function (i, item) {
    IsValidImageUrl(item.data.url, function (url, isvalid) {
        if (isvalid) {
            $('<img/>').attr('src', item.data.url)
                .appendTo('#images')
                .width(500)
                .onclick = function() {Resize()};
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Is the function right?

```
function Resize() {
if (document.getElementById('<img/>').style.width === "500px") {
    document.getElementById('<img/>').style.width = "1000px";
} else {
    document.getElementById('<img/>').style.width = "500px";
    }
}
```

I think the `('<img/>')` might be wrong. I tested it with `('test')` and it worked, so do i need it to be something different? It worked with my test function so the `.click` worked so i think it's trying to change the wrong thing.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? On chrome or firefox's dev console you can use it. Open the developer console, put debugger line inside the function you want to see the variables of. Like this: `function(i, item) { debugger; IsValidImageUrl(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onclick` is a property of DOM elements, not jQuery objects. You should use the `click()` function to add a click handler.

```
.getJSON("http://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/.json?jsonp=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data.data.children, function (i, item) {
        IsValidImageUrl(item.data.url, function (url, isvalid) {
            if (isvalid) {
                $('<img/>').attr('src', item.data.url)
                    .appendTo('#images')
                    .width(500)
                    .click(function() {Resize(this)});
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Your `Resize` function should take an argument telling it which image to change:

```
function Resize(image) {
    if (image.style.width == "500px") {
        image.style.width = "1000px";
    } else {
        image.style.width = "500px";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the 'this' in the .click? the Resize function is just the name i gave to the function, you can do that right?

Comment: `this` in the `.click` is the element that was clicked on.

Comment: I assumed that the point of this is that when the user clicks on one of these images, it resizes that image.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. Is the function right?

    
`function Resize() {
    if (document.getElementById('<img/>').style.width === "500px") {
        document.getElementById('<img/>').style.width = "1000px";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('<img/>').style.width = "500px";
    }
}`

I think the `('<img/>')` might be wrong. I tested it with `('test')` and it worked, so do i need it to be something different? It worked with my test function so the `.click` worked so i think it's trying to change the wrong thing.